# Firefox/Chrome, how to whitelist localhost and wikipedia.org?

Tags: networking, firefox, google-chrome, browser, localhost

On Firefox and Chrome, how do I allow the **local network** and **Wikipedia** (`localhost`, `192.168.1.*`, `*.wikipedia.org`, etc) but block everything else? A whitelist essentially. I still however want other tools on the system to have complete access to the internet, e.g. `git`, `wget`, etc, so the solution must not affect them.

Essentially whitelist the internet on the browser level rather than at the system level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Chrome there is a command line parameter you can use:

```
google-chrome --host-rules="MAP * 127.0.0.1, EXCLUDE wikipedia.org","MAP * 127.0.0.1, EXCLUDE *.wikipedia.org"
```

This maps every domain to localhost excluding wikipedia.

For Firefox create a file `/usr/lib/firefox/distribution/policies.json` with this content:

```
{ 
  "policies": {
    "WebsiteFilter": {
      "Block": ["<all_urls>"],
      "Exceptions": ["*://wikipedia.org/*","*://*.wikipedia.org/*","*://localhost/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

You can find more information about the policies supported by firefox at https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use a userscript (greasmonkey, tampermonkey) to whitelist the web.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name     White List
// @version  1
// @grant    none
// @run-at   document-start
// @match    *://*/*
// ==/UserScript==

var hostname = window.location.hostname;

var allowIPs = true;
var whiteList = [
  "localhost",
  "wikipedia.org",
  "askubuntu.com"
];

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/26445549/473368
var ip = allowIPs && /^(?!0)(?!.*\.$)((1?\d?\d|25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d)(\.|$)){4}$/.test(hostname);

var listed = false;
for (var x in whiteList) {
  if (hostname.indexOf(whiteList[x]) != -1) {
      listed = true;
      break;
  }
}

// Not an IP? Not a whitelisted domain? Block it!
if (!ip && !listed) {
    document.documentElement.remove();
}
```